# Total number of items defined in an enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

How can I get the number of items defined in an enum?

Answer (score 593, accepted):

You can use the static method [`Enum.GetNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames) which returns an array representing the names of all the items in the enum. The length property of this array equals the number of items defined in the enum

```
var myEnumMemberCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length;
```

Comment: Agreed ... here's a link i found http://www.csharp411.com/c-count-items-in-an-enum/

Comment: Could also use Enum.GetValues.

Comment: System.Enum.GetNames, if you aren't already including the System namespace.

Comment: So I just encountered this problem again today; the C style trick as described in other answers below is listed as being problematic but both the Enum.GetValues and Enum.GetNames as listed above seem like they risk allocating a whole new array just to get a fixed length, which seems... well, horrible. Does anyone know if this approach does indeed incur dynamic allocation? If so, for certain use cases it seems far and away the most performant solution if not the most flexible.

Comment: @Xonatron `GetNames` performs about 10 times faster than `GetValues` in my tests, I wonder why.

Comment: @JTrana Yup, I've just traced some unexpected allocation to exactly this: getting this length repeatedly via Enum.GetNames in a loop condition (it wasn't obvious at a glance because it was in the getter of a property). So at the very least, make sure to cache the value somewhere the first time you get it. It's a shame we can't get at this as a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 199):

The question is:

> How can I get the number of items defined in an enum?

The number of "items" could really mean two completely different things.  Consider the following example.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 1,
    D = 3,
    E = 2
}
```

What is the number of "items" defined in `MyEnum`?

Is the number of items 5? (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`)

Or is it 3? (`1`, `2`, `3`)

The number of *names* defined in `MyEnum` (5) can be computed as follows.

```
var namesCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length;
```

The number of *values* defined in `MyEnum` (3) can be computed as follows.

```
var valuesCount = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: Alternative way of writing the last line, `var valuesCount = ((MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))).Distinct().Count();`.

Comment: I cannot think of any developer I've ever met in my life who'd affirm that such an enum contains 3 items.

Comment: @motoDrizzt you can find something like that at an enum of a printer driver like `Default = 1, A4 = 1, Portrate = 1, A4Portrait = 1, Landscape = 2, A4Landscape = 2, ...` ;).

Comment: @Timothy Shields, probably would have been better to say _distinct values_ instead of just _values_

Answer (score 84):

[Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)(typeof(MyEnum)).Length;

Comment: It's faster to use the GetNames method.

Comment: @KasperHoldum Are you running it redundantly in a tight loop or something? Because my next question would be, why?

Answer (score 43):

I've run a benchmark today and came up with interesting result. Among these three:

```
var count1 = typeof(TestEnum).GetFields().Length;
var count2 = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestEnum)).Length;
var count3 = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum)).Length;
```

GetNames(enum) is by far the fastest!

```
|         Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|--------------- |---------- |--------- |--------- |
| DeclaredFields |  94.12 ns | 0.878 ns | 0.778 ns |
|       GetNames |  47.15 ns | 0.554 ns | 0.491 ns |
|      GetValues | 671.30 ns | 5.667 ns | 4.732 ns |
```

Comment: Careful with DeclaredFields ; on a typed enum, using that method adds an extra "SpecialName" entry containing the type of the Enum (e.g. Int32). That adds one extra count compared to what is expected.

Answer (score 21):

A nifty trick I saw in a C answer to this question, just add a last element to the enum and use it to tell how many elements are in the enum:

```
enum MyType {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3,
  NumberOfTypes
}
```

In the case where you're defining a start value other than 0, you can use NumberOfTypes - Type1 to ascertain the number of elements.

I'm unsure if this method would be faster than using Enum, and I'm also not sure if it would be considered the proper way to do this, since we have Enum to ascertain this information for us.

Comment: this is nice since i can do this on XNA because GetNames isn't available there

Comment: Cool trick, this would also be faster than GetNames() because it doesn't have to count them.

Comment: Beware of code that cycles through enums via foreach - you can read off the end of your arrays!

Comment: Also, beware of enums that define their own values - I often use enums for bit flags.

Comment: Also beware of direct enum bindings to some wpf controls such as combobox and listbox

Comment: For what it's worth, this is against the [Microsoft design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum) (see the item "DO NOT include sentinel values in enums")

Comment: This is textbook code smell right here.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Enum.GetNames` to return an `IEnumerable` of values in your enum and then. `Count` the resulting IEnumerable.

`GetNames` produces much the same result as `GetValues` but is faster.

Answer (score 6):

From the previous answers just adding code sample.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int enumlen = Enum.GetNames(typeof(myenum)).Length;
            Console.Write(enumlen);
            Console.Read();
        }
        public enum myenum
        {
            value1,
            value2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you find yourself writing the above solution as often as I do then you could implement it as a generic:

```
public static int GetEnumEntries<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible 
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");

    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).Length;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Basic:

`[Enum].GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length` did not work with me, but
`[Enum].GetNames(GetType(Animal_Type)).length` did.

Comment: Why the downvote? This fixed my problem, it's the correct syntax for VB, even though the question is tagged c#, still useful.

Comment: Downvotes probably because question is tagged C# and this answer didn't mention it wasn't using C#.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this just now, and wasn't happy with the readability of the current solution. If you're writing code informally or on a small project, you can just add another item to the end of your enum called "Length". This way, you only need to type:

```
var namesCount = (int)MyEnum.Length;
```

Of course if others are going to use your code - or I'm sure under many other circumstances that didn't apply to me in this case - this solution may be anywhere from ill advised to terrible.

Comment: This also relies on the enum starting at 0 (the default, but by no means guaranteed). Additionally, it makes the intellisense for normal enum usage *very* confusing. This is nearly always a **terrible** idea.

Comment: That didn't take long :)

Comment: Interesting, I suppose you never know when something better may come about. I made my best attempt at shunning my own solution, but found it interesting enough to share!

Comment: Arguably this route is the most performant if your use case works with the enum starts with 0 case. But please don't call it "Length"..  I use COUNT so it stands out in the intellisense world.  I'll often use ERROR as the default value as well, so it's obvious when something hasn't been set in the pre everything can be nullable worlds..

Answer (score 0):

There is a more concise way with the generic `GetNames()` overload:

```
int itemCount = Enum.GetNames<MyEnum>().Length;
```

[Enum.GetNames<>() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=net-7.0#system-enum-getnames-1)

Answer (score 0):

If it only to know how many items inside the ENUM. I will do this instead:

```
enum MyEnum()
{
  FIRST =  0,
  SECOND = 1,

  TOTAL_ENUM_ITEM
}
```

The last ENUM item `MyEnum.TOTAL_ENUM_ITEM` will show you the number of items inside the ENUM.

It's not fancy, but it works :)