# Getting total number of enum items

Tags: objective-c, c, enums

Is it possible to get the total number of items defined by an enum at runtime?

While it's pretty much the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856154/total-number-of-items-defined-in-an-enum), that question relates to C#, and as far as I can tell, the method provided there won't work in Objective-C.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

An `enum` is a plain-old-C type, therefore it provides no dynamic runtime information.

One alternative is to use the last element of an enum to indicate the count:

```
typedef enum {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    numColors
} Color;
```

Comment: Good for contiguous values, utterly fails for `typedef enum { Red=0xff0000, Green=0x00ff00, Blue=0x0000ff, numColors} Color;`.

Comment: Like Mark said, this will fail big time for his example, the alternative provided by Darren is perfect for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Look here for a better, completely automatic, but potentially dangerous solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24695580/269753

Answer (score 0):

Using preprocessors you can achieve this without the annoying 'hack' of adding an additional value to your enum

```
#define __YourEnums \
YourEnum_one, \
YourEnum_two, \
YourEnum_three, \
YourEnum_four, \
YourEnum_five, \
YourEnum_six,

typedef enum : NSInteger {
__YourEnums
}YourEnum;

#define YourEnum_count ({ \
NSInteger __YourEnumsArray[] = {__YourEnums}; \
sizeof(__YourEnumsArray)/sizeof(__YourEnumsArray[0]); \
})
```