# Return number of Enum Values. ( Size of Enum typedef )

Tags: iphone, enums, typedef

Is there a built in function or a way to query the size of an emun typedef?

```
typedef enum difficultyTypes {
kEasy,
kMedium,
kHard
} difficultyType;
```

I would like a way to query and have it ( in this case ) return 3.
I could even deal with it returning 2 as the highest value ( 0,1,2 ).

Or am I forced to use another int variable that I statically set when I create the enum?

Comment: You could add kMax to the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469358/getting-total-number-of-enum-items).

```
To clarify his answer, looking at your example you could do the following

typedef enum difficultyTypes {
kEasy,
kMedium,
kHard,
kCount
} difficultyType;
```

kEasy would be 0, kMedium is 1, kHard is 2, and kCount is 3, which is the number of elements you have minus itself.